# Microsoft Reporting - Only show footer on particular pages

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm creating a report that generally has two pages.  Each is contained within a Rectangle, and PageBreak values are set on these rectangles to make them appear on separate pages.

Also, the second rectangle should NOT have the footer.  The simplest solution was to put the footer on every-other page.

**THE PROBLEM**:
Occasionally the contents of the first rectangle would go to the second page, putting the second rectangle on the third page.  In these cases the first two pages needed the footer, and the third page should NOT get a footer.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**:
I see where I can put contingent logic on whether to display content in the footer (The "Hidden" property).
Is there a way to add logic to test for the existence of a particular Rectangle on a page?
Something like this to the "Hidden" property:

```
=iif ([Rectangle2 is visible], true, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

On Rectangle1, in "Properties" set PageName = "Main"

On Rectangle2, set PageName = "NoFooter"

In the footer, on the specific textbox's "Properties", for Hidden enter:

```
=iif (Globals!PageName="NoFooter", true, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Globals!PageNumber` and `Globals!TotalPages`; if you want to hide footer on the last page you could set its `Hidden` properties to:

```
=IIf(Globals!PageNumber=Globals!TotalPages, True, False)
```